# Ubuntu live ISO without installer?

Tags: 22.04, iso

I'm trying to extend my "app deployment" app to support deployment ubuntu, but I'm having some trouble.

- Ubuntu Live ISO's are way too big(I want something less than 1GB)
- Ubuntu's live ISO's have an installer built into them, which is something which I don't want

Is there an ISO which can satisfy both conditions?

EDIT:
Why do I need a small ISO for it? Well...

- A small environment which can run applications and can be easily downloaded by anyone.
- For people with only 1 desktop and want to develop for all the platforms, but don't want to have multiple systems dedicated to it.

So I'm creating software to solve The problem

Comment: use Puppy-linux, but not ubuntu. How can you expect a gnome desktop to fit into 1GB?

Comment: Tiny Core or Puppy are what I would recommend. At 300 MB or less Puppy is larger than Tiny Core and is much more powerful.

Comment: Have you looked at ubuntu-core-22-amd64. It's download size is 407 MB. See: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/22/stable/pending/

Comment: Thank you! it's just what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an ISO which can satisfy both conditions?

No. The smallest ISO you can get for Ubuntu is the server version. It will not install a desktop and can be used with a text based installer.

> I'm trying to extend my "app deployment" app to support deployment ubuntu, but I'm having some trouble.

This reads as a PPA would solve your problem.

PPA you can make using [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). Others that like your software can then add your PPA and have your app install into their system.

> [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) is a software collaboration platform that provides:
>
> - Bug tracking
> - Code hosting using Bazaar and Git
> - Code reviews
> - Ubuntu package building and hosting

> [Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas)
>
> Personal Package Archives (PPA) allow you to upload Ubuntu source packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad. You can find out more about PPAs and how to use them in our [help](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) page.

This method is also supported by Debian, and the unofficial Ubuntu versions.